# Enhance the performance of IClassifier

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I am creating a Visual Studio 2017/2019 extension. I am exporting a [IClassifierProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.classification.iclassifierprovider?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) in order to be able to change the formatting of certain C# syntax nodes based on something that requires the access to the semantic model (I am using Roslyn). This means that it is relatively computationally expensive to determine whether to classify a certain node or not. Once the user starts typing in Visual Studio, each typed character results in a new semantic model being generated. This makes the coding experience bad.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to wait some time (e.g. 200 millisecond) before deciding to invoke my classifier? If less than 200ms pass between one character being typed and the other, Visual Studio will wait another 200ms before deciding to invoke the classifier. This means that the classifier will only be invoked after 200ms of the user being idle (not changing the code). This will make the experience much better for the developers using the extension.

The IClassifier interface has a ClassificationChanged event that I can use to tell Visual Studio that some span needs reclassification. I thought about using this. I would return an empty list when GetClassificationSpans is called in the first time, and then invoke ClassificationChanged  asynchronously after some 200 ms. But there seems to be no way to know if the current invocation of GetClassificationSpans was the result of my recent call to ClassificationChanged or not. The contract of IClassifier doesn't even guarantee (as far as I understand it), that it will call GetClassificationSpans  with the same span I passed to ClassificationChanged. E.g. What if it decided to split the span into two? Or maybe merge it with another span?

One solution I am thinking about is to manually monitor the changes in the current document (via the ITextBuffer.Changed event), monitor the time between changes, "enable" the classifier when I think the time is right for classification, invoke "ClassificationChanged" to trigger classification, then "disable" the classifier after classification.

Although this solution might work, is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: `tell Visual Studio to wait some time`, Await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(100)?

Comment: we may use the [IClassifierAggregatorService Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.classification.iclassifieraggregatorservice?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2019) to manage the relationship between source code, and the glyph tags.When an event (e.g. Changed event) of an ITextBuffer interface is raised, we can use the IClassifierAggregatorService Interface to get related IClassifier object (the GetClassifier method), which the tagger casted from.